# VBA: Variable for finding last row stays at first row

Tags: excel, vba

Hello there First post!

-So basically I have this project for updating charts based on a set of data. 
For that I need to find the last row, which works very well with this code:

```
'Chart for PMI

Sheets("Leading Indicators").Select

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ismpmi").Activate

ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Leading Data").range("A2:B872"), PlotBy:=xlColumns

' imagine the next line being bold    
finalrow = Sheets("Leading Data").Cells(Sheets("Leading Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row**

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Leading Data").range("A2:B" & finalrow), PlotBy:=xlColumns

finalrow = 0
```

-Now I want to implement the same code for another sheet and it runs well BUT! finalrow2 stays at 1st row when data goes beyond the 2800 roW. I can't find the reason for it.. any suggestions?? Thanks in advance!

```
'Chart Initial

Sheets("Employment Graphs").Select

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("initial").Activate

ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Employment Data").range("A2:B2780"), _
PlotBy:=xlColumns

' imagine the next line being bold    
finalrow2 = Sheets("Employment Data").Cells(Sheets("Employment Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Employment Data").range("A2:B" & finalrow2), PlotBy:=xlColumns

finalrow2 = 0
```

Comment: May be data is starting from second column but you are finding the last row using first column.

Comment: Hi Shivang, I tried had same result. What's funny is that it works perfectly until row 2799. Once it goes to row 2800 it goes back to row 2.

Comment: finalrow2 = Sheets("Employment Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Wow ok it works. Thank you very much! Im curious why the "used range" works on the other sheet and not on this one? And do you have an idea of why it was stopping at 2800? Just want to understand to avoid doing it in other codes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: May be 2801 st row is empty. Used range only applies upto when it finds an empty row or an empty column. But using cells(rows.count).end(xlup) directly goes to last used row.

Comment: more precisely `UsedRange` is a rectangle range embracing _actually_ (more to be discussed on this…) used cells. So if _actually used_ cells span from row 101 to 120 then `UsedRange .Rows.Count` would yiald `20` and therefore `Cells(20, 1).End(xlUp).Row` would yiald the firts not empty cell row index above row 20

Comment: I will just add for understanding. `.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` works because it goes from the last row (1 million something) and uses end up to get your last row. This is the preferred method of the `.End` usage, but different tools are used for different jobs!

Comment: Perfect thanks you very much!